# How to use simplejson to serialize and maintain properties?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, serialization, simplejson

For a dictionary containing these two key-value pairs:

```
str = StringProperty
time = DateTimeProperty
```

I want to serialize it to JSON, store it in the Datastore, and then fetch it, and deserialize it into the original properties.

Comment: Well I don't really understand the simplejson documentation.  I need to transform a dict into a json string (to store) and then I need to translate a json string back into a dict (to fetch and use).

Comment: StringProperty, DateTimeProperty, etc, are property classes specifically for use with App Engine models. What are you trying to achieve? Why JSON?

Comment: I need to serialize data as part of denormalizing data.  It doesn't have to be JSON.  But note that GAE is on Python 2.5.x and does NOT have cPickle (just Pickle, which is slower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
d = {
  'str'  : StringProperty,
  'time' : unicode(DateTimeProperty)
}
s = simplejson.dumps(d)
print s
```

Comment: Hmmm, so either .dumps and .loads don't require the datatypes indicated in the documentation, or I misunderstand how Python handles dicts/strings/json.

Comment: I don't really understand the reason, but if you try to do simplejson.dumps({'a':87}) it would work well. But if you run simplejson.dumps({'a' : datetime.datetime.now()}) it would fail so that you need to write simplejson.dumps({'a' : unicode(datetime.datetime.now())}). That's really a riddle for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple if your values are strings:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> print simplejson.dumps({'str': 'StringProperty', 'time': 'DateTimeProperty'})
{"str": "StringProperty", "time": "DateTimeProperty"}
```

However, if the values are objects from custom classes (such as the Google App Engine Property classes), they are not JSON serializable.

JSON only serializes simple data types, such as integer/float numbers, booleans, strings, lists/tuples and dictionaries. (See http://www.json.org/ for further details.)

In order to have JSON serializable values, you need to define a way to convert them to simple data types. For example, transforming objects to a tuple containing the class name and the arguments necessary to rebuild them.